# Is it possible to mark Subversion files for selective checkout/access/visibility?

Tags: svn

Hi I have a subversion repository and would like the ability to mark certain files as available/visible/accessible for certain users or certain configurations. Essentially we want fine grain control over which files are present in a checkout/branch/tag etc., based on a nominated role.

I assumed there would be some method of setting up user based visibility on the server, but also thought a specific file/folder property might do instead. Is there a solution that exists for this use case already or is there a clever solution to this using native SVN tools?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, at least on a per directory basis to set [access control](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.auth.general). With this, you can set the ability to checkout and commit changes as two separate accesses. For example, someone checkout (*read*) the code, but not commit changes (*write*) while someone else can checkout and commit changes (*read* and *write*).

If you don't mind about visibility, and simply want to control the ability to commit changes, you can use my [pre-commit](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Precommit-Kitchen-Sink-Hook) hook.

This hook will allow you to assign permissions down to the file level and will use LDAP/Windows Active Directory groups for permissions.

Most of the time, I find that I can use LDAP settings to limit which groups have access to a particular repository (for example, only developers and people in QA should be able to see the repository at all), but once you do that, no one cares about making individual directories or files invisible to others as long as you can define who can make changes. My hook can do that.

I prefer to use separate repositories (which can be served by a single Apache instance) to keep one group's eyes away from another group's files rather than trying to use Subversion's access controls to do that.

Comment: Specifically what I'd like to do is be able to have a checkout/branch/tag that only contains the file subset we want for a given role and be able to maintain that on a file by file basis. Ultimately the files will be deployed as a set to an external developer. An example usage might be to take a checkout under a given user and have the checked out files only include those with a given property.

Comment: There's no way to do that in Subversion via property. After all, properties themselves are versioned information. One version may have a property, and another doesn't. It would be like checking out files based upon their content.

Comment: David I don't actually see any inconsistency with a checkout based on file content. If a checkout has a certain 'role' attached with it, the file list associated with that role can be generated using any means really and file content is fully available to the subversion engine. Metadata is even more accessible as it is stored directly in the repository.

Comment: Having to examine and process each file would slow down the checkout. Plus, what if that *property* disappeared. Would that user still have access to older versions? Could someone who has access give someone access by merely putting in a special property? Could someone deny access by deleting that *property*. Will all users be able to do this? How do you prevent a change that would cause this? It's possible to design a version control system to do this, but none of the ones I know do. (Continued)

Comment: (Continued) Remember this is version control. If someone made changes they shouldn't, you can always revert. No one can make a change anonymously. Their name is plastered on each change. This in itself disciplines the process. If someone isn't authorized to make a change, and they did, they could pay the consequences. In my years as a CM, I've rarely ever seen someone do something they shouldn't. Lock too many doors, and you spend more time locking and unlocking them than getting actual work done. Your employees are professionals. Treat them as such.